# Laravel - faile to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, artisan

Al acceder a `http://localhost/inspecciones` obtengo el siguiente error:

```
ErrorException (E_WARNING) 
file_put_contents(/opt/bitnami/apps/ACP_GDELS/storage/framework/views/2340879ffb6f6078205b94fdb24edcc6929ef7c4.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Pero el archivo `/views/2340879ffb6f6078205b94fdb24edcc6929ef7c4.php` no existe.

Aun así, he ejecutado el siguiente comando para otorgar los permisos al directorio `/storage`:

```
chmod -R 755 /storage
```

Desconozco el por qué no funciona correctamente. Añado el siguiente código que devuelve el debugger Laravel:

[image]

Comment: Sergio, qué te regresa el comando ls -la en la carpeta raiz?

Comment: En la ruta raíz me aparece lo siguiente `drwxrwxr-x  5 administrador www-data        4096 dic 15 14:37 storage`

Comment: Si editas tu pregunta agregando lo que regresa un ls -la en la carpeta raíz de tu proyecto podemos diagnosticar mejor el problema. Tal vez le hacen falta permisos a la carpeta bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer, tienes un problema de permisos en el directorio `storage`.

De la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation#configuration):

> #### Permisos de directorio
>
> Después de instalar Laravel, es posible que deba configurar algunos permisos. Los directorios dentro de
>   `storage` y los directorios `bootstrap/cache` deben poder ser escritos
>   por su servidor web o Laravel no se ejecutará.

Entonces, para hacer esto, cambia la propiedad de la carpeta a tu usuario y al grupo del servidor, agregandole la opción `-R` para hacerlo recursivo a todos las subcarpetas y archivos que contiene.
Si el usuario/grupo del servidor es `www-data`, hazlo de esta manera:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data ./storage
```

Luego define los permisos que tienen las carpetas y archivos:

```
find ./storage -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;

find ./storage -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

Para la carpeta `bootstrap/cache`:

```
sudo chown $USER:www-data ./bootstrap/cache -R

find ./bootstrap/cache -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

¿Que significan esos permisos?

***775***
El propietario y el grupo del directorio tienen acceso completo. Todos los otros pueden enumerar el directorio, pero no pueden crear archivos ni borrarlos.

***664***
El propietario y el grupo pueden leer y escribir en un archivo, mientras que todos los demás sólo pueden leer el archivo.

***Nota***: estos comandos funcionan en sistemas basados en *nix.

Comment: He realizado las instrucciones que me comentas, pero no hay manera. Ahora también me da error de permisos en el directorio `/opt/bitnami/apps/ACP_GDELS/storage/logs/laravel-2019-06-04.log`por lo que no puedo ni entrar en el `index`

Comment: que extraño. uso esos mismos permisos en todos mis proyectos. tal vez sea por el usuario del servidor, ¿sabes si es http o www-data? para apache en ubuntu el default es 'www-data', pero no sé que sistema ni que servidor estás usando.

Comment: El ususario es www-data

Comment: ok, edité la respuesta para www-data

Answer (score 0):

sospecho que el comando que has hecho no se habrá ejecutado como esperabas..Asunto permisos nuevamente. Añádele a tu comando la opción -f para que sea forzado.

```
chmod -Rf 755 /storage
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Sólo me funciona si asigno permisos totales `chmod -R 777 /storage` pero creo que no es una solución correcta.