# fopen(F:\wamp64\www\project\public): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

Estoy importando un archivo csv, en laravel utilizando el plugin Maatwebsite\Excel.

Tengo un archivo csv con 26961 registros,
cuando elimino registros y dejo unos 10mil registros, este importa bien, cuando hago la prueba ya con 15mil registros o mas, ya me marca el error:

> fopen(F:\wamp64\www\project\public): failed to open stream: Permission
> denied

Yo uso wampserver, sobre windows 10.

No se si es problema de permiso de windows, o problema de configuracion del permiso de laravel.

en el config de excel. tengo:

```
'temporary_files' => [
   'local_path'          => storage_path('framework/laravel-excel'),
   'remote_disk'         => null,
   'remote_prefix'       => null,
   'force_resync_remote' => null,
```

y en mi filesystems.php que trae por defecto en laravel tengo:

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        ],

    ],
```

en mi Import yo implemento WithBatchInserts, de esta manera, como importa los primeros 10mil, considero que todo esta bien configurado, excepto algun permiso.

```
class ProductoImport implements ToModel, WithBatchInserts, WithChunkReading
.... codigo....

public function batchSize(): int
    {
        return 1000;
    }

    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 1000;
    }
```

que puedo hacer? donde puedo configurar para solucionar este error?:

```
    ErrorException
    fopen(F:\wamp64\www\project\public): failed to open stream: Permission denied

    Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError
F:\wamp64\www\project\vendor\maatwebsite\excel\src\Files\TemporaryFile.php:56



*/

    public function sync(): TemporaryFile

    {

        return $this;

    }

 

    /**

     * @param string|UploadedFile $filePath

     * @param string|null         $disk

     *

     * @return TemporaryFile

     */

    public function copyFrom($filePath, string $disk = null): TemporaryFile

    {

        if ($filePath instanceof UploadedFile) {

            line 56>>>> $readStream = fopen($filePath->getRealPath(), 'rb');

        } elseif ($disk === null && realpath($filePath) !== false) {

            $readStream = fopen($filePath, 'rb');

        } else {

            $readStream = app('filesystem')->disk($disk)->readStream($filePath);

        }

 

        $this->put($readStream);

 

        if (is_resource($readStream)) {

            fclose($readStream);

        }

 

        return $this->sync();

    }

}
```

Comment: Sería bueno ver la traza completa del error. El mensaje refiere un problema de permisos. En la pregunta pareces sugerir que el error ocurre a partir de una determinada cantidad de archivos, pero si te permite leer un archivo, debería permitirte leer `N` archivos. A no ser que a partir de una determinada cantidad de archivos uso otro tipo de código o archivos alojados en otra carpeta donde no tendrías permiso. Sin la traza completa del error y sin entender todo el contexto es difícil poder determinar el problema. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Gracias ya agregué el error completo.

Comment: Es posible que falten directorios y/o permisos en tu proyecto. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/269243/29967) y también [esta de SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35102519/5587982).