# Error 500 y local.ERROR: mkdir(): Invalid path al subir imágenes a "Public_html/storage/images/"

Tags: php, laravel, fileupload, cpanel, php8

Estuve desarrollando un proyecto en Laravel 10 y uno de los puntos a tratar era el de subir imágenes a mi cPanel con información a la que cualquiera pudiese acceder
Para esto, desarrollé el sistema en 3 archivos distintos: UploadController, imageUpload.blade.php y FileUpload.php
El problema está en que, al querer subir un archivo, siempre tengo un error 500, junto con este mensaje:

```
[2023-09-03 23:52:50] local.ERROR: mkdir(): Invalid path {"userId":447,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): mkdir(): Invalid path at /home/mesadeco/mclcp_web/app/Lib/FileUpload.php:74)
[stacktrace]
```

En base a lo que he revisado, el problema se encuentra en el FileUpload.php, en donde tengo configurado el directorio al que se subirá, etc. Este es el código de mi archivo para subir imágenes:

```php
<?php
    namespace App\Lib;
    
    use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;
    use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;
    
    class FileUpload
    {
        protected $file;
        protected $container;
        protected $fullPath;
        protected $fileName;
        protected $resizes = [];
        protected $fileUploaded = null;
        protected $dates = true;
        protected $originalSave = true;
        protected $temp = false;
        protected $maxWidth = 1000;
        protected $maxHeight = 1000;
    
        public function __construct($file, $path = 'files/', $container = 'asset')
        {
            $this->file = $file;
            $this->container = $container;
            $this->path = $path;
        }
    
        /**
         * Enable or disable original Save
         */
        public function setOriginalSave($bool = true)
        {
            $this->originalSave = $bool;
        }
    
        /**
         * Add Resizes
         * @param $prefix
         * @param null $width
         * @param null $height
         */
        public function addResize($prefix, $width = null, $height = null)
        {
            $this->resizes[$prefix] = [
                'width'     => $width,
                'height'    => $height
            ];
        }
    
        public function setTemp($bool = true)
        {
            $this->temp = $bool;
        }
    
        public function uploadImageSave()
        {
            $fileName = Uuid::uuid4()->toString().'.'.$this->file->extension();
            $dates = $this->dates ? Date('Y-m-d').'/' : '';
            $this->path = 'storage/'.$this->path.$dates;
            $this->path = 'storage/'.$this->path.$dates;
    error_log("Valor de this->path: " . $this->path);
    
            var_dump($this->path);
            $this->fileName = $this->path.$fileName;
            if($this->temp) {
                $this->fullPath = storage_path('temp/'.$this->path);
            } else {
                $this->fullPath = public_path($this->path);
                $division = explode('/', $this->path);
                $base = '';
                for($i=0; $i < count($division); $i++) {
                    if ($base != '') {
                        $base .= '/';
                    }
                    $base .= $division[$i];
                    if(!is_dir(public_path($base))) {
                        mkdir(public_path($base), 0777, true);
                    }
                }
            }
    
            //dd($this->fullPath);
    
            //Creando directorio
    
            //Resizes
            $img = Image::make($this->file->getRealPath());
    
            //Llenando datos de file uploaded
            $this->fileUploaded['filesize'] = $img->filesize();
            $this->fileUploaded['width'] = $img->width();
            $this->fileUploaded['height'] = $img->height();
            $this->fileUploaded['originalName'] = $this->file->getClientOriginalName();
            $this->fileUploaded['extension'] = $this->file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $this->fileUploaded['mime'] = $this->file->getMimeType();
            $this->fileUploaded['cache'] = $dates.$fileName;
            $this->fileUploaded['url'] = asset($this->fileName);
    
            //Cargando resizes
            foreach ($this->resizes as $prefix => $res) {
                $img->resize($res['width'], $res['height'], function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                });
                $img->save($this->fullPath.$prefix.'_'.$fileName);
                $this->resizes[$prefix]['url'] = asset($this->path.$prefix.'_'.$fileName);
            }
    
            //Guardando original
            if($this->originalSave) {
    
                if($this->fileUploaded['width'] > $this->maxWidth || $this->fileUploaded['height'] > $this->maxHeight) {
                    if($this->fileUploaded['width'] > $this->fileUploaded['height']) {
                        $img->resize($this->maxWidth, null, function ($constraint) {
                            $constraint->aspectRatio();
                        });
                    } else {
                        $img->resize(null, $this->maxHeight, function ($constraint) {
                            $constraint->aspectRatio();
                        });
                    }
    
                    $img->save($this->fullPath.$fileName);
                } else {
                    $this->file->move($this->fullPath, $fileName);
                }
            } else {
                if(file_exists($this->file->getRealPath())) {
                    unlink($this->file->getRealPath());
                }
            }
        }
    
        public function setDates($bool)
        {
            $this->dates = $bool;
        }
    
        public function getResizes()
        {
            return $this->resizes;
        }
    
        public function getFileName()
        {
            return $this->fileName;
        }
    
        public function getFileUploaded()
        {
            return $this->fileUploaded;
        }
    }
```

Este también es el código que tengo en filesystems.php:

```php
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
    
    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
        public_path('images') => storage_path('app/images'),
    ],
    

],
```

Comment: Tengo fylesistems configurado de esta manera: 
   ` 'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
        
        'links' => [
            public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
            public_path('images') => storage_path('app/images'),
        ],
        

    ]`
Está bien?

Comment: Si,  eso parece estar ok, agregalo a la pregunta mejor, que esta dificil de leer ahi. Me referia a si creaste los links con `php artisan storage:link`.Por otro lado el mesaje dice `mkdir(): Invalid path...`, lo que podria ser tambien un tema de permisos

Comment: ¿Dónde podría revisar eso?¿En los permisos de escritura de mi carpeta?

Comment: Los permisos basicamente son de escritura para el usuario del servidor en los directorios `/bootstrap/cache` y `/storage` podes ver mas aca https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/269118/laravel-faile-to-open-stream-permission-denied/269243#269243

Comment: Por otro lado seria util que nos muestres los valores de `$this->fullPath` y `$fileName` justo antes de hacer `$img->save($this->fullPath.$fileName);` y `$this->file->move($this->fullPath, $fileName);`

Comment: Cuando mencionas los valores de  `$this->fullPath` y `$fileName`,¿te refieres a lo que muestra la consola como valores?